# problem with swf object for uploading image file

Tags: php, jquery, flash, uploadify

i have just got this script from one of the site for uploding images into my site www.drf-stact.co.cc 
Where i am unable to view upload button in i.e less than 8 and it is working well with FF and crome... please guide me to make it work in i.e 6,7,8.

Thanks in adavance.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
      <!--for the uploadify-->
      <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="css/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        //uploadify:
        $("#uploadify").uploadify({
            'uploader'       : 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : 'scripts/uploadify.php?setit=customename',
            'cancelImg'      : 'cancel.png',
            'folder'         : 'images',
            'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
            'auto'           : true,
            'multi'          : true,
            'queueSizeLimit' : 5,
            'fileDesc'       : 'jpg, gif',
            'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.gif',
            'sizeLimit'      : '204800',//max size bytes - 200kb
            'checkScript'    : 'scripts/check.php', //if we take this out, it will never replace files, otherwise asks if we want to replace
            'onAllComplete'  : function() {
                                    //$('#switch-effect').unbind('change');
                                    //$('#toggle-slideshow').unbind('click');
                                }
        });

      }); 
      </script>
      <title>AD-Gallery + Uploadify + classe.upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <!--uploadify-->

        <div style="float:left;">
            <div id="fileQueue"></div>
            <div>you can select more than one file at once</div>
            <input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />
            <p><a href="javascript:jQuery('#uploadify').uploadifyClearQueue()">Cancel All Uploads</a></p>
        </div>
    <a href="index.html">back</a>  

    </body>
    </html>
```

please follow this link to download all scripts used for my image upload. [click here to download rar file of 160kb only](http://cid-b88405bc51ef157b.office.live.com/self.aspx/images%5E_upload%5E_script/imageuploader.rar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. please enable flash player add on in ie or update it to new.
2. You can also check it -

   if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9.0.18")) {
   $('.messagediv').html('Ideal Image Dimension 400 x 200 to upload.');
   }
   else {
   $('.messagediv').html('Flash player disabled or not installed, please install flash    player add-on plugin to browser.');
   }

Comment: Dear - Amolv, Flash player add on is updated. i have checked it either.

Comment: plz dont think so, just install shockwave flash object add on in ie, uplodify will work.